# How to select the options condition?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, syntax, conditional-statements

```
    $cmb->add_field( array(
    'name'             => 'Select Video or Image',
    'desc'             => 'Select an option',
    'id'               => 'the_wiki_id_one',
    'type'             => 'select',
    'show_option_none' => true,
    'default'          => 'custom',
    'options'          => array(
        'standard' => __( 'Option One', 'cmb2' ),
        'custom'   => __( 'Option Two', 'cmb2' ),
        'none'     => __( 'Option Three', 'cmb2' ),
    ),
) );
```

Above is the code. Now suppose If I have chosen Option two, and I want to execute a logic Like this →

```
If (Option 2 selected) {
 <?php Then execute some PHP code ?>
}
```

Option 2 selected → layman Language. How can we do this in terms of programming one?

Above is a code from [CMB2 Wordpress Plugin](https://github.com/CMB2/CMB2/wiki/Field-Types#checkbox)

Comment: where should that condition be placed, somewhere near $cmb->add_field ?

Comment: No somewhere else in theme.

Comment: You have to make some kind of JavaScript for the onChange event and call a PHP script with an Ajax request.

Comment: I dont think so. I think the solution should be pretty simple. It should be some boolean. If option 2 selected is true then execute some php code.

Comment: [Connection of this quetsion](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/275477/checkbox-on-a-meta-box-using-cmb2-plugin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i get it right, then you just need to get that value from post meta, and make condition.

```
$the_wiki_id_one = get_post_meta($post_id, 'the_wiki_id_one', true);

// Option 2 is selected
if( 'custom' === $the_wiki_id_one ){
 //Then execute some PHP code
}
```